# java webscoket client for Rabbit mq Stomp

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

I am looking for creating a websocket client for using rabbit mq stomp over websocker using java.
I using jetty client and i am getting org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Didn't switch protocols

Comment: Please clarify and include the relevant code etc..

Comment: WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
 client.start();
 ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
 URI wsUri = URI.create("ws://localhost:15674/stomp");
 Future<Session> future = client.connect(socket,wsUri,request);
 future.get();

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with the Rabbit MQ version. After I've upgraded from Ubuntu default one to the newest Rabbit MQ version from https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html  it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example: [stomp-websockets-java-client](https://github.com/nickebbutt/stomp-websockets-java-client/blob/master/stomp-java-client/src/main/java/com/od/helloclient/HelloClient.java)

Please read first:

- http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/
- http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/14/introducing-rabbitmq-web-stomp/

> not perfect, it's far from the worst way do messaging in the browser: exposing STOMP through Websockets.